# Mysql SELECT function inside mysql LIMIT function

Tags: mysql, limit

```
SELECT COUNT('2018-02-12') 
as ids FROM tg_partner_data
WHERE assign_to = '2'
AND
followup_date = '2018-02-12' AND active='Y'
LIMIT (SELECT count FROM tg_master_count WHERE count_for = 'followup')
```

I tried to get count as output but this query doesnot works . I am using like this because the limit setting is dynamic.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html says:
"LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants" You can also use parameter placeholders or integer variables, but not subqueries or other syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An immediate problem with your use of `LIMIT` is that you have no `ORDER BY` clause.  *Which* first records do you expect from the result set?  This is not clear.  I will give a generic pattern which you can use to have a subquery limit the number of records.

Consider a simple table with just one column:

```
col
1
2
3
4
5
```

Now let's say that you want to limit the number of records in the result set, based on an ordering of `col`, using some subquery.  We can write the following:

```
SET @rn=0;

SELECT col
FROM
(
    SELECT
        col,
        @rn:=@rn+1 rn
    FROM yourTable
    ORDER BY
        col
) t
WHERE t.rn <= (SELECT 3 FROM dual);    -- replace with your own subquery
```

### Demo

The basic idea here is that we simulate row number in a subquery, that is, we assign a row number to each record, ordered according the the `col` column.  Then we subquery that table, and retain only records matching the subquery you want to use to limit.

Comment: count is a field name.

Comment: @soorajspillai Your query is in a mess, with many problems.  I'm going to update with a generic pattern you can use.  2 minutes please.